# Circle or geometrical equations

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAXof.jpg]
Hey guys,

Can you help me with the easiest way to find the value of x?

Comment: Pythagoras theorem

Comment: I tired to apply Pythagoras theorem but couldn’t able to figure out. Can you help me step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If circle radius is $50\ cm$, then notice that $|OB| = |OC| = 50\ cm$. If we use Pythagoras Theorem in the triangle $AOC$, we get $|AO| = 40\ cm$. Therefore, $x = |OB|-|AB| = 50 - 40 = 10\ cm$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I edited the answer, this way it is more clear. You're welcome.

Comment: @user268699 You can accept the answer if it helps, by clicking the green tick.